# How to send emails with React without EmailJS?

Tags: library, javascript, email, node.js, react

I tried using EmailJS but it didn't work since I was using material UI text fields. EmailJS does seem a bit too complicated to use though. I was just wondering if there is a better library to use that is just a setup on the web and then send function passing in the send to, send from and message.